# Is it possible to create a non-modifiable hashtable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, readonly-collection

I am familiar with creating read-only variables and constants in PowerShell by using the `Set-Variable` command with something like this:

```
Set-Variable -Option ReadOnly, AllScope -Name STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS -Force -Value @{
                Username = 'username'
                Password = 'password'
                ClientId = 'clientID'
            }
```

Or alternatively to sub `ReadOnly` with `Constant` for non-removable variables.

I assumed that with the `ReadOnly` option I would not be able to modify the collection, but this isn't the case. For example, `$STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS.someNewEntry = 'newEntry'` is valid and modifies the collection accordingly.

Are there similar commands that I could use to create a real 'ReadOnly' collection in PowerShell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The options `ReadOnly` and `Constant` are *variable* (data-holder) concepts: they only prevent *assigning a new value* to the variable, they don't prevent modification of the *value* that a read-only/constant variable immutably stores.

To also prevent modification of the value (object) itself, you must additionally use a read-only *data type*<sup>[1]</sup> to store in the read-only/constant variable. To get a read-only hash table (dictionary), use the generic [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary[TKey, TValue]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary-2) type:

```
Set-Variable -Option ReadOnly, AllScope -Name STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS -Value $(
    $dict = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[string, string]]::new(
      [System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase
    )
    $dict.Add('Username', 'username')
    $dict.Add('Password', 'password')
    $dict.Add('ClientId', 'clientID')
    [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary[string, string]]::new($dict)
)
```

Note:

- Unfortunately, you cannot directly initialize a `ReadOnlyDictionary[TKey, TValue]` instance from a PowerShell `[hashtable]`, because a *generic* `IDictionary`-implementing instance with *matching types* is required; therefore, an auxiliary [`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionar[TKey, TValue]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary-2) instance is used.
- Note the `[System.StringComparer]::OrdinalIgnoreCase` argument passed to the aux. dictionary, which ensures that key lookups are case-*insensitive*, the way they are by default in PowerShell `[hashtables]`.<sup>[2]</sup>
- While the resulting `$STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS` read-only variable's *value* is then effectively also read-only, accidental attempts to modify the read-only dictionary result in error messages that aren't obvious, as of PowerShell Core 7.1:

  - `$STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS['Username'] = 'foo'` unhelpfully reports: `Unable to index into an object of type "System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyDictionary`2[System.String,System.String]`
  - `$STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS.Add('foo', 'bar')` unhelpfully reports: `Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "2"`
  - `$STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS.Clear()` unhelpfully reports: `Cannot find an overload for "Clear" and the argument count: "0".`
  - Only using *dot notation* provides a helpful error message: `$STANDARD_TOKEN_PARAMS.Username = 'foo'` reports `Collection is read-only.`
  - [GitHub issue #15118](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/15118) proposes improving these error messages.

---

<sup>[1] This isn't *always* necessary, namely not if the value is an instance of a by definition *immutable* .NET primitive type (a property-less type such as `[int]`) or a `[string]`.</sup>

<sup>[2] Note that `[hashtable]` in *Windows PowerShell* and (obsolete) PowerShell Core versions 6.1 and below use `[System.StringComparer]::CurrentCultureIgnoreCase`, i.e, *culture-sensitive* lookups instead - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/27376) for background information.</sup>